# Calculation of composite integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, warning-messages, integral-equations

I am facing trouble calulating the following integrals. Could you give me any advice?

My code is the following:

```
u = 0.9;

A[x_, t_] := Re[N[AiryAi[x - u*t + I*u*t - t^2]]*Exp[I*t (x - u*t - t^2 + u/2)]*
Exp[x - u*t - t^2]*Exp[I*(x - u*t)]]

A1[x_, t_] := A[x, t]* Conjugate[A[x, t]]

Sh[t_] := NIntegrate[-Re[A1[x, t]]*Log[Re[A1[x, t]]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
Method -> "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 8]

ShT = Table[{t, Sh[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning behind this choice of options? `Method -> "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 8`

Comment: @rhermans I tried to define the simplest conditions. There is no specific reason behind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following parameter choice will work:

```
Sh[t_] := 
 NIntegrate[-Re[A1[x, t]]*Log[Re[A1[x, t]]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   Method -> "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> 12, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 12]

ShT = Table[{t, Sh[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain why do you choose these conditions for working precision etc.? If I want to form a table for 100 values of "t" and not only 10, what should I do?

Comment: I read the error message and then increased the working precision and max. recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The following produces the table up to `t = 10` in under 7 sec. on my laptop:

```
u = 0.9;

ClearAll[A, A1];
A[x_, t_] := 
  Re[AiryAi[x - u*t + I*u*t - t^2]]*Exp[I*t (x - u*t - t^2 + u/2)]*
   Exp[x - u*t - t^2]*Exp[I*(x - u*t)];

A1[x_, t_] = Simplify[Abs[A[x, t]]^2, {x, t} \[Element] Reals];

Sh[t_] := 
  NIntegrate[-A1[x, t]*Log[A1[x, t]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
   Method -> "DoubleExponential"];
ShT = Table[{t, Sh[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
(*
  {{0, 0.937074}, {1, 0.643354}, {2, 1.51625},       {3, -2.7694},
   {4, -382.593}, {5, -31421.3}, {6, -4.49781*10^6}, {7, -1.28387*10^9},
   {8, -7.67179*10^11}, {9, -9.82327*10^14}, {10, -2.73103*10^18}}
*)
```

The time increases rapidly with `PrecisionGoal`. For settings of 4, 5, 6, it takes just under 3, 8, 16 seconds respectively.

With working precision settings other than `Automatic` or `MachinePrecision`, arithmetic is done with arbitrary-precision software which uses a 64-bit mantissa for precisions less than `$MachinePrecision` $\approx 15.95$. Machine precision uses hardware arithmetic which is faster and uses a 53-bit mantissa (normally, these days). Usually one uses `WorkingPrecision` settings of 16 or higher, unless there is a specific reason for using less.  Furthermore, `u = 0.9` and `N[]` convert to machine precision, rendering settings of `WorkingPrecision` other than `Automatic` or `MachinePrecision` rather useless.

`MaxRecursion -> 20` was used because I got a `NIntegrate::ncvs` error, and it allowed `NIntegrate` to use extra recursion when needed.

The use of `N[]` and some `Re[]` are unnecessary, and I removed them.  Simplifying `A1[]` speeds things up a bit.

*Remark:* `Sh[19]` didn't finish while I typed this answer.